# What's wrong with this iterator declaration

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

I have a method in my class, here it is:

```
void TextQuery::build_word_map()
{
   word_map = new map<string,loc*,less<string>,allocator<string> >;
   typedef map<string,loc*,less<string>,allocator<string> >::value_type value_type;
   typedef set<string,less<string>,allocator<string> >::difference_type  diff_type;

   set<string,less<string>,allocator<string> > exclusion_set;

   ifstream infile( "exclusion_set" );
   if ( !infile )
    {
      static string default_excluded_words[25] = {     "the","and","but","that","then","are","been", "can","can't","cannot","could","did","for",
            "had","have","him","his","her","its","into",     "were","which","when","with","would"};
      cerr << "warning! unable to open word exclusion file! -- "  << "using     default set\n";
      copy( default_excluded_words, default_excluded_words+25, inserter(exclusion_set,     exclusion_set.begin()));
    }
  else 
    {
      istream_iterator<string, diff_type> input_set( infile ), eos;
      copy( input_set, eos, inserter( exclusion_set, exclusion_set.begin() ));
    }


   vector<string,allocator<string> > *text_words = text_locations->first;
   vector<location,allocator<location> > *text_locs = text_locations->second;
   register int elem_cnt = text_words->size();
   for ( int ix = 0; ix < elem_cnt; ++ix )
    {
      string textword = ( *text_words )[ ix ];
      if ( textword.size() < 3 || exclusion_set.count( textword ))
         continue;
      if ( ! word_map->count((*text_words)[ix] ))
        { 
            loc *ploc = new vector<location,allocator<location> >;
            ploc->push_back( (*text_locs)[ix] );
            word_map->insert( value_type( (*text_words)[ix],ploc ));
        }
      else (*word_map) [(*text_words) [ix]]->push_back( (*text_locs) [ix] );
    }
}
```

, when I try to build it, I'm told that it's impossible to transform "std::ifstream" into "std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &"?
What does this mean, and what do I do (except studying iterators in-depth, that is ;-) )?

Comment: Can you give the exact error?

Comment: Please can you give us an minimal crashing code, and the line where the error appear ?

Comment: Your allocator is the wrong type.

Comment: error C2664: std::istream_iterator<_Ty,_Elem>::istream_iterator(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &): can't cast parameter 1 from "std::ifstream"into "std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string,
1>              _Elem=diff_type,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<diff_type>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Elem=diff_type,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<diff_type>
1>          ]

Comment: Yes, I see how it should be the wron iterator, but somehow ifstream_iterator wasn't recognised as in my IDE.

Comment: And yes, the line causing the error is 'istream_iterator<string, diff_type> input_set( infile ), eos;'

Answer (score 3):

You have error, since you use `diff_type` as `second` template parameter.
If you want use `diff_type` you should declare `istream_iterator` properly, declaration should be

```
istream_iterator<string, char, std::char_traits<char>, diff_type>
```

Since `istream_iterator` is really

```
template< class T,
          class CharT = char,
          class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
          class Distance = std::ptrdiff_t >
class istream_iterator
```

as you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)

Comment: That actually worked) Thanks. Any tips on how do I avoid such mistakes in the future?